# C# can I access an enum without full qualified names

Tags: c#, enums

I have a C# enum type that ends up with very long qualified names.  e.g.

```
DataSet1.ContactLogTypeValues.ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice.
```

For readability, it would be nice if I could tell a particular function to just use the last portion of the name, something like...

```
{
    using DataSet1.ContactLogTypeValues;
    ...
    logtype = ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to do anything like this in C#?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can define the enum outside of a class, so at least you'll skip the `DataSet1.` part.

Comment: Check out using an alias: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You cannot create an alias for an actual enum *value*, but you can create an alias for the enum *type*, like so: `using ContactLogTypeValues = YourNamespace.DataSet1.ContactLogTypeValues;`. For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `using` directive to specify an alias. It will exist everywhere in the file, not in one particular method though.

Comment: Thanks, alias is pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Since C# 6, you can use `using static`:

```
using static DataSet1.ContactLogTypeValues;
...
logtype = ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice;
...
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this might not be the solution you envisioned, but it does allow you to write the code you are requesting.

```
enum ContactLogTypeValues
{
    ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice,
    AnotherValue1,
    AnotherValue2,
    AnotherValue3
};

static ContactLogTypeValues ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice = ContactLogTypeValues.ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice;
static ContactLogTypeValues AnotherValue1 = ContactLogTypeValues.AnotherValue1;
static ContactLogTypeValues AnotherValue2 = ContactLogTypeValues.AnotherValue2;
static ContactLogTypeValues AnotherValue3 = ContactLogTypeValues.AnotherValue3;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = ReminderToFollowupOverdueInvoice;

}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this approach, but really didn't want to go down that route.  :)  It does make the function code look nice, although at the expense of a mess of useless variables.