# Can I access enums without having to type out the enum type?

Tags: c#

```
Enum EventType = {Click, Jump, Etc};
```

Instead of accessing it like like this:

```
EventType.Jump
```

is there any way to do so without the "EventType." prefix?

```
Jump
```

Comment: Is "`Enum EventType = {Click, Jump, Etc};`" valid C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# can I access an enum without full qualified names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110871/c-sharp-can-i-access-an-enum-without-full-qualified-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the other answers, you can't omit the enum prefix in C#, however, if the goal is prevent having to type long enum names (although intellisense solves that quite a bit), or keep shorter code, you *can* use an alternative by putting an alias inside the using clause on top. (although this will only be valid inside that specific class)
e.g.

```
using s = SomeLongEnumerationNameYouDontWantToSee;
...
if(foo == s.Bar) ..
```

or a real world enum:

```
using ds = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle;
...
ds.Solid
```

Answer (score 5):

No, but if you really want, you can use local references in you class for that:

```
class A
{
   private EventType Jump = EventType.Jump;


   if(actionEvent.Type == Jump)......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually not. In C++ this was actually a long standing pain in the neck as scoped enums were not possible up to C++11 (without workarounds)

For C# you cannot do this as this would potentially introduce name collisions eg:

```
Enum EventType1 = {Click, Jump, Etc};
Enum EventType2 = {Click, Jump, Etc};
```

Which `Jump` should be used now?

Comment: One could argue that it would depend on the type of the variable or parameter, e.g. `EventType1 type = ...` but I'm not sure if that would hold water.

Comment: One could also argue that you can just reference one of these in a local scope e.g. `{ using EventType1; Foo(Jump); Foo(Click); }` And in this local scope, we know it's `Jump` from `EventType1` because we referenced it in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No. You can't use an enum member with using `EnumType.`

Instead of `Enum` you can define a `const int Jump = 1` and then code accordingly, **but**

**Why do you want something like this ?**

Consider using `enums` instead of const, It will improve readability.